# ¿Cómo puedo centrar una ventana con formulario usando window.open()?

Tags: javascript

He creado un formulario con algunos campos que debe ser mostrado en una ventana. El problema es que no consigo centrarla, que aparezca en medio de la pantalla. He usado este código y no funciona para cumplir ese objetivo:

```
var anchoVentana = 300;
  var altoVentana = 225;

// Calcular las coordenadas para centrar la ventana en la pantalla
    var left = (screen.innerWidth - anchoVentana) / 2;
    var top = (screen.innerHeight - altoVentana) / 2;
    var tituloVentana = "Listado de campañas";  
    var nuevaVentanaCampainaReport =    window.open('', '_blank', 'width=' + anchoVentana + ', height=' + altoVentana + 

', left=' + left + ', top=' + top+',title=' + tituloVentana);


nuevaVentanaCampainaReport.document.open();
 nuevaVentanaCampainaReport.document.write(superContainer.innerHTML);
nuevaVentanaCampainaReport.document.close();
```

¿Por qué en este caso no puedo centrar la ventana? Gracias

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4068373/center-a-popup-window-on-screen

Comment: [¿Parecida?](/questions/205670)